# "new ephemeral certificate expires too soon: current time:"M

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I've been connecting to Google Cloud Platform MySQL from the CloudSQL Proxy on Windows for years. All of a sudden, I'm unable to connect.

When I start the proxy using PowerShell, it launches fine and says ready for new connections. Then when I try to connect to it on 127.0.0.1, the client will report back:
"Lost connection to MySQL server during query (127.0.0.1:3306)"

The CloudSQL Proxy will report in the terminal:
"error: new ephemeral certificate expires too soon: current time: 2019-06-28 23:54:29 +0000 UTC, certificate expires: 2019-06-28 16:54:25.8818364 -0700 PDT m=+291.599345701"

Any ideas what would  have caused this change and what to do about it?

My GCE instance and Python code are still able to interact with the database just fine.

I also tried connecting from the Cloud Shell and get:
"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root' gcp mysql"

Comment: Its 2019 and Microsoft are still confused about time zones. Set your hardware clock to UTC and telll your OS to use the local timezone.

Comment: @symcbean THANK YOU SO MUCH. So simple. Didn't think for a second it was an issue with my local machine since a buddy of mine couldn't connect either. Do you want to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 6):

Its 2019 and Microsoft are still confused about time zones. Set your hardware clock to UTC and telll your OS to use the local timezone.

Be warned - this may break other things which interpret the time on your machine using inconsistent methods - do go through a reboot cycle to check everything is working as it should.

Comment: Upvoted it, but my reputation is too low for it to publicly impact the score. Thanks again!